# Why does GNU awk implementation limitations does not seem to work in practice?

Tags: awk, gawk

[This page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Implementation-Limitations.html) that mentions the GNU awk implementation limitations mentions that the limitation on the size of a field and the size of a literal string is `MAX_INT`.

However, when I declare a long string literal as a variable and try to find its length with the `length` function, the function seems to break when the string is more than 308 characters long. Example below:

```
BEGIN {
  avar=1234... #309 characters
  print length(avar) #prints 3 but prints right length when length < 309
}
```

However, the following command line works for 1000 characters:

`echo 1234... | awk '{print length($1)}' #tested and works for 1000 characters`

I am on a CentOS 7 system and my awk version is 4.0.2.

Any suggestions as to why this discrepancy?

Comment: It works with a string, i.e. quoted. But your 309 characters are (presumably) all numeric. That is out of range for a double. I bet your length (avar) is 3 because it contains either "Inf" or "NaN" (Infinity or Not A Number).

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it. yes, it works in a quoted string.

Comment: Additional: external data read into awk is string until proved otherwise. Values defined in the the code are parsed, and a numeric value is treated as integer. If you mention 0 + $1, it may revert to Inf or NaN there, too.

Comment: @mkc :  MAX_INT means the value that can be hold in integer or something else ?

Comment: @ETL_Devs  It's a well-known C constant. Although it can vary with architecture, the usual understanding is 2^31.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do may be easier to repeat with:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  avar='"$(printf '%0200d' 0)"' #309 characters
  print avar,length(avar) #prints 3 but prints right length when length < 309
} '
```

Which prints `0 1`, which means that the whole list of 200 zeros is converted to one single `0` by awk, which seems to imply that that is the **value** of the integer written with 200 zeros.

Lets give it some other value (an 8 followed by 200 zeros):

```
➤ awk 'BEGIN {
  avar='"$(printf '8%0200d' 0)"' #309 characters
  print avar,length(avar) #prints 3 but prints right length when length < 309
} '
799999999999999975786497770008289327579602620364018901185934007602774787484432604273570707237650014944220099327791059265457085874946227877115080328377919022968188728534319854489454506449337030839107584 201
```

Which is the float approximation to `8e200`. Which is easily confirmed with:

```
➤ awk 'BEGIN {
  avar='"$(printf '8%0200d' 0)"' #309 characters
  print avar,length(avar) #prints 3 but prints right length when length < 309
  printf "%15e\n",avar
} '
799999999999999975786497770008289327579602620364018901185934007602774787484432604273570707237650014944220099327791059265457085874946227877115080328377919022968188728534319854489454506449337030839107584 201
  8.000000e+200
```

So, a number given in a code assignment (`avar=`) is (correctly) processed as a numeric value.
A double float could store only up to an exponent of 308 (without including sub-normals). So, no numeric value of more than 308 digits could be converted to a float.

```
➤ ➤ awk 'BEGIN {
  avar='"$(printf '8%0308d' 0)"' #309 characters
  print avar,length(avar) #prints 3 but prints right length when length < 309
  printf "%15e\n",avar
} '
inf 3
            inf
```

However, as an string, surrounded with double quotes (`avar="..."`) there is no problem.

```
➤ awk 'BEGIN {
  avar="'"$(printf '8%0600d' 0)"'" #309 characters
  print avar,length(avar) #prints 3 but prints right length when length < 309
} '
8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 601
```

In the case where the data comes from a pipe (or a file) the data is assumed to be an string (unless coerced to be converted to a number with `data + 0` or similar) and its length is its number of characters.

```
$ printf '8%02000d0\n' 0 | awk '{print length($1)}'
2002
```